# Three.js move and rotate the center of geometry

Tags: three.js

I have a complex model loaded with OBJLoader. I want to move and rotate its center to let the user ( the user of my application ) to place the center point where he/she wants.
I'm aware of this: [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911065/three-js-move-geometrys-center), but for me does not work.
This is a test in fiddle : [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/68kn8/3/)

Pressing the button in the example I expect that the center is moved.
The code in the button is :

```
objMesh.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0.1, 0.1)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution empirically, but I don't understand why it works.
I post the code to help and maybe someone could explain me what I found.

The code below shift the center in x for 0.1 units.

```
var x = 0.1;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++)
{
    var geometry = object.children[i].geometry;

    object.children[i].centroid.divideScalar(geometry.vertices.length); // Why this line ?

    var offset = object.children[i].centroid.clone(); 
    object.children[i].geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-offset.x+x, -offset.y+y, -offset.z+z));
    object.children[i].position.x -= x;
    object.children[i].position.y -= y;
    object.children[i].position.z -= z;
    object.children[i].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
mesh.geometry.translate( x, y, z );
```

or

```
mesh.geometry.center();
```

Also, consider just calling `mesh.position.set()`, rather than moving each vertex of the geometry.

three.js r.95

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I don't want to move or resize the shape, but only move or rotate the center.
For example I would like to place the center in the one of the corner. Or for example rotate the center so it does not allign with the world coordinate system.

Comment: 1. what do you mean by "rotate the center"? 2. a geometry does not have a "center" property.

Comment: I mean that: if you try to rotate the model, it rotates around its center. I want to move this center. 
The problem is that I import models from a CAD system and the orientation of the axes do not match with the center calculated with a bounding box. So if I try to rotate or stretch ( change the scale) an imported shape, the result is not correct.
For example if I import a cube that it is not aligned with the x,y,z axes, the result of rotare/resize is totally wrong. I hope I made my self clear

Comment: OK, try `THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry )`, which translates the geometry so that the center of the geometry's bounding box is at the origin.